# rails_env is 'production' always using Nginx/Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

There is the following nginx host config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name production2.somedomain.co;
  root /home/engine/domains/production2_web_app;
  client_max_body_size 2m;
  rails_env production2;
  location /api {
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    root /home/engine/domains/production2_app/current/public;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

As you can see my application 'rails_env' is 'production2', but when I try to open my production2 URL I see data from database 'production'. Also, there is the following nginx config on the same server:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name production.somedomain.co;
  root /home/engine/domains/production_web_app;
  client_max_body_size 2m;
  rails_env production;
  location /api {
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    root /home/engine/domains/production_app/current/public;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

'production' app works good, I see 'production' database data. What is the trouble? How can I set 'production2' environment?

Comment: I guess, since you are using the same port same configurations are loaded. Try changing the port and see?

Comment: I use different server names

Comment: In the location /api block, you are specifying rails_env=production again. Is it causing the issue?

Comment: Yes. Please create the answer and I will mark it

Comment: Done. Btw just curious, is it really necessary to specify rails_env in twice? It seems redundant to me

Answer (score 0):

In the production2 config, you need to change rails_env production to rails_env production2.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name production2.somedomain.co;
  root /home/engine/domains/production2_web_app;
  client_max_body_size 2m;
  location /api {
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production2;
    root /home/engine/domains/production2_app/current/public;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```